# Keras: difference between a Layer and a Model, or when to implement a Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am looking at the [advanced Keras tutorial on the tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention), and I am a little bit puzzled by the implementation of the Bahdanau attention:

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.Model):
  ...
```

So it seems that they are implementing it as a `Model`. However, it is not in itself a complete, useful model -- it is just a part of a larger `Model` (a decoder in the present case) that is being optimized. It is used later as

```
attention_layer = BahdanauAttention(10)
```

which emphasize the fact that it can be seen as just a layer of a `Model`.

Actually, once one realize that a model can be reused as just a part of another model, the boundary between a `Model` and a `Layer` become a bit blurry.

So my questions are,

1. What is the difference between a `Layer` and a `Model` in Keras, and
2. When is it appropriate to implement a layer as a `Layer`, as opposed to always implement a new layer as a `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused. Functionally, a layer and a model are completely different and I don't see why you they need to be compared. In other words, a Model is usually a collection of Layers. It is your responsibility to add them to the model and connect them. They can be connected in various and intricate ways. Sure, you can create a model that only has one layer, but that depends on what you are using it for.

As for your second question, there really isn't a guideline on when to do what. Usually you try to exhaust all options until you find what works best. Chaining models and sharing layers between models could be a defining factor in making your decision whether you just want a simple layer, or plug it into a model.